# Implementation of Heap (ADT) using Array Vs. LinkedList

Tags: arrays, linked-list, heap, time-complexity, abstract-data-type

In my data-structure course, I need to implement a binary heap with the following time - complexity requirements:

- Find Max - O(1)
- Insert - O(lg n)
- Delete Max - O(lg n)

Now I thought to implement this using an array in the following way: The root of the heap is in Arr[1] (the first index). The children of Arr[i] are in Arr[2i] and Arr[2i+1] (2 children).
With this implementation I will get Find Max in O(1), Delete Max in O(n) and insert in O(lg n) with an exception - if I need to insert when the array is full I will have to resize the array and will "cost" me O(n) so the total cost of insert with all edge cases will be O(n) instead of O(log n) as required.

Is there other way of implementation that answers all the complexisty requirements?
I thought maybe to try to implement with a LinkedList instead of an array but insert will still be O(n). Any suggestions for an implementation will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation can satisfy the requirements. I assume that when you say delete max will take O(n), you are thinking that you need to shift the entire array over one position? What you actually need to do in that case is have have the next largest element 'swim' to the top as they say. This only requires O(lgn) time.

Also the resizing does not happen often so the *amortized* runtime is still O(lgn). [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).

Comment: Thank you actually I meant to write that "delete max" is O(log n) by using the 'swim' technic you mentioned. My problem is with the Insert - I know that the amortized runtime is O(log n) but I need the worst-case run time to be O(log n) and that what makes me think that maybe I shouldnt implement this heap using array but in a different way...

Comment: Ok I see. One thought taken from that wikipedia article *The motivation for amortized analysis is that looking at the worst-case run time per operation can be too pessimistic*. I think you have the correct implementation. See [this powerpoint](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/24PriorityQueues.pdf). Your current implementation is still considered to be O(lgn).

Comment: Alright. so I'll probebly leave the implementation like this. Thank you